# Trouble finding a simple SQL Join Solution

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2005, join

I looked up what I could, but could not find the same problem.

I am using the following SQL to attempt to generate the results that I am looking for.
I am trying to accomplish a join or another function that will allow me to Count or Select rows from the left side that have matching rows on the right side. If there is a matching column on the right side, I only want it to be counted once. 
I am looking to see if at least one match (and count it as 1 even if they are more) for it to be counted.

This is what I am trying to do.

Left Side
Annual_Capture (ID)

1 Some Data

2 Some Data

3 Some Data

Right Side (Annual Comments)

2 Comment for Annual Capture id  2

2 Another Comment for Annual Capture id 2

Result:
From a select it would only return Annual_Capture (ID) of 2. 
From a count, it would return only the record on Annual_Capture (ID 2)

In my case I keep getting a count of 2 instead of one.

Here is the SQL I am using:

**COUNT**:

```
 SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Annual_Capture
 JOIN Annual_Comments
 ON Annual_Capture.id = Annual_Comments.Record_id 
 where Main_AbstractNumber = 133 and Year = 2012 ;
```

**SELECT**

```
 SELECT * FROM Annual_Capture INNER JOIN Annual_Comments
 ON Annual_Capture.id = Annual_Comments.Record_id WHERE Main_AbstractNumber = 133
 AND Year = 2012
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
select
    count(distinct Annual_Capture.id) 
from
    Annual_Capture

    inner join Annual_Comments
        on Annual_Capture.id = Annual_Comments.Record_id 
where 
           Main_AbstractNumber = 133 
    and    Year                = 2012
;
```

Comment: Thank you, thats awesome! Works perfectly for the count! Now I have to figure out how to get the select statement to work as well for the SELECT part I listed above to list the actual full records in Annual_Capture that have one comment or more (once). Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This only returns rows from Annual_Capture where there is at least one comment (which is how I read your rqmts):

```
SELECT Annual_Capture.id, count(Annual_Comments.*)
FROM Annual_Capture JOIN Annual_Comments ON Annual_Capture.id = Annual_Comments.Record_id 
WHERE Main_AbstractNumber = 133 and Year = 2012
GROUP BY Annual_Capture.id
HAVING Count(Annual_Comments.*) >= 1;
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that in SQL Server 2005, it did not like the Annual_Comments.*. It kept saying error near *